# Click on a button/link within a table, run a query, and display the contents in a modal

Tags: javascript, jquery, sql, coldfusion, modal-dialog

I am looking for a solution to my problem.  I have a dynamically built table with multiple rows.  The table is populated based on search criteria, from another page, so the number of rows per search will vary each time.  Each row has 32 columns.  I am trying to build a button/link on each row to display specific data from that row in a modal.  I am developing  with html, coldfusion, and simplemodal.  I have the functionality of the modal working and I can display content in the modal properly.  My problem is no matter which button I click, the modal displays data from the last record.

Sample Rows:

button  |  Fay  | Smith  | 113 East Street | Columbus | OH | 5551214 | etc...

button  |  Joe  | Smith  | 111 East Street | Columbus | OH | 5551212 | etc...

button  |  Jim  | Smith  | 112 East Street | Columbus | OH | 5551213 | etc...

When I click on the button for each row, I want the data to appear in the modal.  My current code only shows content from the last row no matter which button is clicked.

My current code:

```
<CFQUERY name="Detail" dataSource="MTD">
    SELECT * FROM TABLEDATA  WHERE ID = #ID_FROM_SEARCH#
</CFQUERY>

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="global.css" media="all" />
<link type='text/css' href='css/basic.css' rel='stylesheet' media='screen' />
</head>
<body>


<tr>
    <div id='basic-modal'>
    <!-- modal content -->
    <h3>Detail Report</h3>
    <input class="basic" type="image" alt="RECORD DETAILS" height="25" width="25" src="report.jpg">
    </div>  


    <div id="basic-modal-content">
        <TABLE border=0 cellpadding=1 cellspacing=1>

            <CFOUTPUT query="Detail">
            <TR>
            <TD valign=top>First Name</TD>
            <TD valign=top>#Fname#</TD>
            </TR>

            <TR>
            <TD valign=top>Last Name</TD>
            <TD valign=top>#LName#</TD>
            </TR>

                        ...
                        ...
                        ...

    </TABLE>        
        </CFOUTPUT>
    </div>
</tr>

<script type='text/javascript' src='includes/modal/jquery.js'></script>
<script type='text/javascript' src='includes/modal/jquery.simplemodal.js'></script>
<script type='text/javascript' src='includes/modal/basic.js'></script>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: There is nothing in your cfoutput block that shows a clickable item.

Comment: The clickable item is  <input class="basic" type="image" alt="RECORD DETAILS" height="25" width="25" src="report.jpg">

Comment: I am just showing the code pertaining to the modal and what I want displayed.  I am not showing how the table is built.

Comment: Your `<cfoutput></cfoutput>` tags are badly nested, you're going to have multiple closing `</table>` tags but only one opening `<table>` - this probably won't help

Comment: There is nothing in your clickable item that resembles a record identifier.

Comment: Dan, that is correct and I believe that is part of the problem.  I have tried to add record identifiers with no success. I have tried removing the input and making it an anchor tag then pointing to another cfm file but that didn't work either.  It caused the modal window to be blank.

Answer (score 0):

Here is my suggestion on code changes

```
<CFOUTPUT query="Detail">
    <img class="basic" alt="RECORD DETAILS" height="25" width="25" src="report.jpg" data-ID="#Detail.ID#">
      <div id='basic-modal-#Detail.ID#'>
        <!-- modal content -->
        <h3>Detail Report</h3>
        <div class="basic-modal-content">
            <TABLE border=0 cellpadding=1 cellspacing=1>
                <TR>
                <TD valign=top>First Name</TD>
                <TD valign=top>#Fname#</TD>
                </TR>
                <TR>
                <TD valign=top>Last Name</TD>
                <TD valign=top>#LName#</TD>
                </TR>
            </TABLE>   
        </div>
    </div>
</CFOUTPUT>
```

put the click listerner on the image itself. Then use the data attribute of the image that gets clicked to display the correct modal content. You can then wrap the image in divs and style it how you want to get the separation of records for you user so they know what to do with the buttons being shown. I recommend saving tables for tabular data only. save input fields for when you really need an input and using `<tr>` outside of a table is not good practice. It will cause a W3c validation error.